# Field is not a stored field, only stored fields (regular or many2many) are valid for the 'groupby' parameter in Odoo 15

Tags: group-by, model, odoo-15

In the model, I added a Many2one field that is `teacher_id` and related to `res.users`, then i added `teacher_gender` that related to `teacher_id.gender`.

```
teacher_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='Teachers', required=True, tracking=True)
teacher_gender = fields.Selection([('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female'), ('other', 'Other')], string='Gender', related='teacher_id.gender', tracking=True)
```

And in the view, I added like this:

```
<record id="school_teachers_search" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">school.teachers.search</field>
    <field name="model">school.teachers</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <search string="Teachers">
            <field name="name"/>
            <field name="photo"/>
            <field name="teacher_age"/>
            <field name="teacher_dob"/>
            <field name="teacher_gender"/>
            <field name="teacher_blood_group"/>
            <field name="nationality"/>
            <separator/>
            <filter name="teacher_age_old" string="Age More Than 40" domain="[('teacher_age', '>=', 40)]"/>
            <filter name="teacher_age_young" string="Age Less Than 40" domain="[('teacher_age', '&lt;', 40)]"/>
            <filter name="teacher_gender" string="Male" domain="[('teacher_gender', '=', 'male')]"/>
            <filter name="teacher_gender" string="Female" domain="[('teacher_gender', '=', 'female')]"/>
            <separator/>
            <!-- filter for archive / unarchive -->
            <filter string="Archived" name="inactive" domain="[('active', '=', False)]"/>
            <separator/>
            <group expand="0" string="Group By">
                <!-- group by name is difference than field name, or else will be issue when set context in ir.actions.act_window below -->
                <filter string="Gender" name="group_teacher_gender" domain="[]" context="{'group_by': 'teacher_gender'}"/>
            </group>
            <!-- search panel is a left sidebar filter -->
            <searchpanel>
                <!-- add searchpanel teacher_gender to this view causing issue -->
                <field name="teacher_gender" string="Gender" icon="fa-cutlery" color="#875A7B" enable_counters="1"/>
                <field name="teacher_blood_group" select="multi" string="Blood Group" icon="fa-truck" enable_counters="1"/>
            </searchpanel>
        </search>
    </field>
</record>

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_school_teachers">
    <field name="name">teachers</field>
    <field name="res_model">school.teachers</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form,kanban</field>
    <field name="domain">[]</field>
    <!-- set default group by and filter -->
    <!-- add search_default_group_teacher_gender to this view causing issue -->
    <field name="context">{"search_default_group_teacher_gender": 1, "search_default_teacher_age_old": 1}</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Create new teacher
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

And after that, i get this issue when i come to teacher page:

> Field school.teachers.teacher_gender is not a stored field, only stored
> fields (regular or many2many) are valid for the 'groupby' parameter

[image]

You can search "causing issue" in this post, and see that which code causing the issue, i've comment those codes to ignore the issue, but i still want to know how to fix the problem.

Full code of this module you can file in: 
https://github.com/saxsax1995/odoo-15-school/blob/master/school/models/teachers.py 
https://github.com/saxsax1995/odoo-15-school/blob/master/school/views/teachers.xml

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `store = True` when defining `teacher_gender` as a related field. Under the hood, related field is nothing but a kind of calculated field. If you want to use any calculated field in a search or group or filter in odoo then you need to store it in the database. By default related fields are not stored.